# Select next element of any li with the dynamic selector using CSS or js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't find out the way to get this.

```
<ul>
    <li class=""></li>
    <li class=""></li>
    <li class=""></li>
    <li class=""></li>
    <li class=""></li>
    <li class=""></li>
    <li class=""></li>
    <li class=""></li>
</ul>
```

And apply dynamic class to li onclick using js.
then select the next li to apply some extra css.

```
<ul>
    <li class=""></li>
    <li class=""></li>
    <li class=""></li>
    <li class="test"></li>

    *******<li class=""></li>

    <li class=""></li>
    <li class=""></li>
    <li class=""></li>
</ul>
```

Now i want to apply css on *******li.

Hope my question is clear.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$('li.test').next('li')` https://api.jquery.com/next/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use css selectors in javascript, so you can do something like this:

```
var yourListItem = document.querySelector("li.test + li");
```

here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h9xcvug4/) for you

Comment: Not matched, What happen when .test is assigned dynamically. Its not working

Comment: @webtuts4u what you mean by dy assigned dynamically??

Comment: if the `test` class is added dynamically just run my line of code after you added the class

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li").on("click", function(){
  $(this).addClass("yourclass");
  $(this).next("li").css("backgroung-color","red"); //add css
});
```

Comment: Not match with my question. Its not li, li with dynamic class asiged. Already tested. Not Working

Comment: `And apply dynamic class to li onclick using js` this is your statement.. @webtuts4u

Answer (score 1):

**.next** can only return the immediate next sibling

```
$('li.test').on('click', function() {
    $('li.test').next('li').css("color", "red");
});
```

and to change the color of ******* you need to put them in li tag, as follows:

```
<li class="">*******</li>
```

Also you can use **$(this) instead of $('li.test')** as said by @empiric

Comment: inside your `click`-function you can use `$(this)` instead of `$('li.test')`

Answer (score 1):

I think no need for jquery use the css tag that will do the same thing

it will Select `<li>` elements that are placed immediately after .test class

ex:http://jsfiddle.net/Muthukumaru/q64tLhf5/

```
 li.test + li{
   **Your css styles **
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use below cod  . read more about [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/opvek49h/)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('li.test').next('li').css('color','red');
 });
```

For click event

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('li.test').on('click',function(){
    $(this).next('li').css('color','red');
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try like this

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('li.test').next('li').css('color','green')
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class=""></li>
    <li class=""></li>
    <li class=""></li>
    <li class="test"></li>

    <li class=""></li>

    <li class=""></li>
    <li class=""></li>
    <li class=""></li>
</ul>
```